# Applescript: Attempt to set name property of class fails silently

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to change the name of a layer in Wirecast.

Script Debugger's Dictionary view says that access to the name property of the layer class is get/set, and that the type is text.

I can read the layer name, but I can't set it.  The attempt to set it does not throw an error.  The script runs to completion silently.   Here's the code:

```
tell application "Wirecast"
    activate
    set myDoc to last document

    set myLayer to layer 2 of myDoc
    set oldName to name of myLayer
    set newName to "NewLayerName"
    set name of myLayer to newName

end tell
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong. Looks like a bug. Not only should they fix that, they should allow getting properties of an object, like "get properties of layer 2 of document 1". You should contact the developer.